# How to convert a SVG to a PNG with ImageMagick?

Tags: svg, imagemagick, png

I have a SVG file that has a defined size of 16x16. When I use ImageMagick's convert program to convert it into a PNG, then I get a 16x16 pixel PNG which is way too small:

```bash
convert test.svg test.png
```

I need to specify the pixel size of the output PNG. `-size` parameter seems to be ignored, `-scale` parameter scales the PNG **after** it has been converted to PNG. The best result up to now I got by using the `-density` parameter:

```bash
convert -density 1200 test.svg test.png
```

But I'm not satisfied, because I want to specify the output size in pixels without doing math to calculate the density value. So I want to do something like this:

```bash
convert -setTheOutputSizeOfThePng 1024x1024 test.svg test.png
```

So what is the magic parameter I have to use here?

Comment: e.g. `-size 1024x1024` is working fine, what is your imagemagick version?

Comment: ImageMagick version is 6.6.9.7. Maybe it depends on the SVG? My SVG defines a fixed size of 16x16 in the header and all coordinates are absolute values and not percent values or something like this.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/516095/bake-an-svg-image-into-a-png-at-a-given-resolution

Comment: ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q16. convert -resize 1024x1024 foo.svg foo.png works fine.

Comment: @Jichao `-resize` just stretches the converted image, with poor quality results.

Comment: `convert -size 1024x1024 test.svg test.png` works fine with ImageMagick 7.0.7-0 Q16 (current version in Chocolatey repo for Windows). Just make sure that `-size` appears before the input filename, else a 16x16 picture will be upscaled to give a blurry result.

Comment: FYI ImageMagick is pretty awful when it comes to SVG conversions. For example, it's text positioning is [broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53417436/imagemagick-svg-to-png-conversion-screws-up-text-position). I found that a better option was to use a Node module that leverages PhantomJS, like [svg2png](https://github.com/domenic/svg2png).

Comment: @Futal you should post your comment as an answer. It may not have been available when OP posted this but in 2022 it's better than the existing answers imo

Answer (score 725, accepted):

I haven't been able to get good results from ImageMagick in this instance, but [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/release/) does a nice job of scaling an SVG on Linux and Windows:

```bash
# Inkscape v1.0+
inkscape -w 1024 -h 1024 input.svg -o output.png
```

```bash
# Inkscape older than v1.0
inkscape -z -w 1024 -h 1024 input.svg -e output.png
```

Note that you can omit one of the width/height parameters to have the other parameter scaled automatically based on the input image dimensions.

Here's the result of scaling a 16x16 SVG to a 200x200 PNG using this command:

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 as far as imagemagick is concerned. There seem to be problem with the SVG engine. In most cases I wasn't able to get accurate results with it. Inkscape, OTOH, works perfectly fine.

Comment: I think Inkscape is the single most impressive example of OSS after Linux itself. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Works nicely on OSX too.

Comment: Great. My problem wasn't changing the size, but that ImageMagick turned transparent areas in the SVG into white areas in the PNG. Inkscape preserves the transparency correctly.

Comment: Another positive thing is that Inkscape is way faster than imagemagick's convert.

Comment: You can use -d 1200 to also set the DPI.

Comment: On OSX, with Inkscape installed for X11, it worked for me using: `/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/bin/inkscape -z -e test.png -w 1024 -h 1024 test.svg`

Comment: Note: Inkscape does not seem to have an option to respect the aspect ratio when exporting. If you need that, try using `rsvg` (or `rsvg-convert`) instead.

Comment: @Rörd To keep background transparent with ImageMagick, use `-background none` command line option.

Comment: Inkscape is badass. On mac setup an alias `alias inkscape="/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/bin/inkscape"`

Comment: This works wonderfully on OSX. I installed inkscape with homebrew cask (http://caskroom.io/)  and the command worked out of the box.

Comment: I was able to install this on OSX using homebrew with `brew install homebrew/x11/inkscape`

Comment: @DenilsonSá : If you specify only the width OR the height, Inkscape will keep aspect ratio.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, to set white background with inkscape instead of default transparency : `-b white`.

Comment: Nice solution. The only issue is that it shows a GUI prompt for every image I want to convert. What's the right way to suppress that? edit: Never mind, my command was wrong. Properly written it does not produce any outputs of any kind.

Comment: Recent versions on OS X change the current working directory. I assume there are good reasons for this but it means you need to use absolute paths for the file arguments.

Comment: Building using this method doesn't have this problem: https://inkscape.org/en/download/mac-os/#alternative_install_0.92 Sounds like the issue is whether it's installed in `/usr/local/bin/inkscape` as a binary, or as a script that changes `CWD` and `exec`s the binary in `/Applications`.

Comment: Batch convert in one line using bash and Inkscape:
If you want to convert all the svg files in a directory to a specific size (30x30):
`for file in *.svg; do inkscape -z -e "${file/.svg/.png}" -w 30 -h 30 $file; done`

Comment: Inkscape just wrecks my SVG. It's like it's ignoring transform declarations, but also printing some stuff black which doesn't have a background colour when rendered correctly.

Comment: @Trejkaz I've never seen that happen before, so I'm not sure what could be the problem. One of the above comments recommends using `-background none` to keep the transparency. I also looked around a bit and found that there is [an Inkscape bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1430716) which you could be running into...

Comment: That bug might account for the black backgrounds on some of the elements, for sure. The text not being transformed is a bit terrible too, but svgexport is doing that as well, so at the moment my best idea for converting is to use phantomjs.

Comment: Just to add a note: You can use just single parameter between width and height and the other parameter will scale automatically. For example you may just use -w 1024 and -h will scale automatically.

Comment: By the way, what this does is the following: Using Inkscape, without a GUI, export to `test.png`, with `1024` pixels in width and `1024` pixels in height, from `test.svg`.

Comment: I just installed Inkscape 1.0.1 for Ubuntu and it has a "-o" option as a an alternative to "export-filename". Haven't checked Mac yet but I imagine it is the same, thus avoiding the difference in the OS's.

Comment: I also noticied this correctly handled a gradient background for my icon where magick convert did not

Comment: On Inkscape 1.0 (4035a4fb49, 2020-05-01) - Win10 - export-filename requires `=` or as @crowmagnumb said use `-o`

Comment: I edited to add what I see as some more common use cases more directly first since I just keep coming back here, feel free to revert if you feel otherwise, cheers.

Comment: ImageMagick by now has no more issues rendering SVG, is better documented, makes it easy to export at specific resolution or target height/width

Comment: With imagemagick `convert img.svg -background none -size 1024x1024 img.png` works perfectly

Comment: @qubodup imagemagick (newest version at time of writing) still completely fails with nested `<svg>` and `<use>` references. Even inkscape only drew half of the image file I have to png. It renders fine in various browsers and passes validation so the file is fine. I ended up having to install pip: `cairosvg` was the only one able to successfully rasterise the complex svg I have

Comment: The given command opens the GUI and I need to give additional input. I found that this is perfect, quick, does not open the GUI: `inkscape --convert-dpi-method=none -o output.png --export-overwrite -D --export-png-color-mode=RGBA_16 input.svg`

Comment: @Luciano what is your Inkscape version? And which of the above commands were you using? (there is one for older installations, and one for Inkscape 1.0+)

Comment: @808sound I'm using Inkscape 1.3. The command I use is this: `inkscape --convert-dpi-method=none -o output.png --export-overwrite -D --export-png-color-mode=RGBA_16 input.svg`. I'll try to edit the answer to add it.

Comment: hey @808sound SO won't let me edit because of "too many pending edits... lol". I just noticed this is your answer, so maybe you can edit it. Another reason I also chose Inkscape is that it exports all objects regardless of their position, while ImageMagik's convert exports the page boundaries which may result in cropping or extra empty space. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Luciano, I just double-checked, and the current answer works just fine using Inkscape 1.3.2 on Ubuntu 22.04. So I don't think an edit is needed. BTW the command you mentioned seems dangerous, since the `--export-overwrite` allows overwriting the _input_ file, which is not usually the desired behavior!

Answer (score 195):

Try [**svgexport**](https://github.com/shakiba/svgexport):

```bash
svgexport input.svg output.png 64x
svgexport input.svg output.png 1024:1024
```

svgexport is a simple cross-platform command line tool that I have made for exporting svg files to jpg and png, see [here](https://github.com/shakiba/svgexport) for more options. To install svgexport [install npm](https://www.google.com/search?q=install%20node%20and%20npm), then run:

```bash
npm install svgexport -g
```

Edit: If you find an issue with the library, please [submit it](https://github.com/shakiba/svgexport/issues/new) on GitHub, thanks!

Comment: svgexport worked great for me. Output matches browser rendering much more closely than ImageMagick.

Comment: this worked well for me as well. Real time saver compared to doing it manually in a GUI tool. Quite difficult to find a GUI app on mac in the cheaper range anyway that handles SVG well

Comment: svgexport didn't do anything for me on OSX, just ended up with blank image

Comment: Works great, but produces a huge image. Using optipng, I was able to compress my text logo down from 3 megabytes to ~20kB.

Comment: Inkscape did not work well on MacOS but this one did the job,  Good job !

Comment: @Timmmm Can you please [submit an issue](https://github.com/shakiba/svgexport/issues/new) on GitHub with an example?

Comment: Actually I think it may work; turned out my SVG relied on implicit image dimensions which are (I think) part of SVG 2. Chrome renders them fine, but I guess they've started implementing SVG 2.

Comment: @AliShakiba Can you please guide how can I use it on Windows. Even better, if you can tell me how can I use your code in my Visual Studio 2015 application?

Comment: @ubaabd Can you please open an issue on github? It is difficult to discuss it in comments.

Comment: @AliShakiba Just did that. The issue is open on github.

Comment: evgexport creates HUGE png files depending on the size. Recommend svg2png which also uses PhantomJS for export, but creates much smaller images.

Comment: Agree with @Aaron_H, I tried both and [svg2png](https://github.com/domenic/svg2png) does this better. svgexport produced a huge 308 KB file while svg2png produced same quality file at 25 KB.

Comment: `svg2png` doesn't rotate line markers (such as arrow heads) correctly for me and the PNG produced was bigger than the one from `svgexport`, which renders the SVG exactly  as in the browser (while Inkscape didn't load the remote font). So +1 from me for `svgexport` as the only tool who accomplished what I was looking for.

Comment: Exactly what I've been looking for for a long time. Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 150):

This is not perfect but it does the job.

```bash
convert -density 1200 -resize 200x200 source.svg target.png
```

Basically it increases the DPI high enough (just use an educated/safe guess) that resizing is done with adequate quality. I was trying to find a proper solution to this but after a while decided this was good enough for my current need.

> **Note:** Use 200x200! to force the given resolution

Comment: Opacity and shadows lost in my case.

Comment: I don't have complex svg so this worked for me. `-resize 200%` did not work and I had to specify size in pixels.

Comment: @jiyinyiyong To keep background transparent with ImageMagick, use `-background none` command line option. To keep image ratio, you also could specify only one dimension like `-resize 200` for width or `-resize x200` for height. See: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry for exhaustive _ImageMagick geometry_ options.

Comment: doesn't work for me either. The result is all blurry.

Comment: (this applies to linux, may apply to windows) if you turn -verbose on IM then it would appear that IM itself uses inkscape to create an intermediate eps file. therefore i would suggest using inkscape directly as suggested by @808sound

Comment: And the batch version is ```for file in ./*.svg; do convert -density 1200 -background none -resize 200x200 $file `basename $file .svg`.png; done```

Comment: Be careful: it approximates curved paths with segments https://i.stack.imgur.com/foL91.png

Comment: Convert first to PNG (since background white does not work), then take the PNG and convert to PNG or JPG (with white background).

Answer (score 96):

Inkscape doesn't seem to work when svg units are not `px` (e.g. cm).  I got a blank image.  Maybe, it could be fixed by twiddling the dpi, but it was too troublesome.

Svgexport is a node.js program and so not generally useful.

Imagemagick's convert works ok with:

```bash
convert -background none -size 1024x1024 infile.svg outfile.png
```

If you use `-resize`, the image is fuzzy and the file is much larger.

**BEST**

```bash
rsvg-convert -w 1024 -h 1024 infile.svg -o outfile.png
```

It is fastest, has the fewest dependencies, and the output is about 30% smaller than convert.  Install librsvg2-bin to get it:

```bash
sudo apt install -y librsvg2-bin
```

There does not appear to be a man page but you can type:

```bash
rsvg-convert --help
```

to get some assistance.  Simple is good.

Comment: This is easily the best answer (I don't know why twenty different answers give the same imagemagick response); it preserves colors and shadows and doesn't mangle anything. However, to match the imagemagick resize behavior (in particular, WxH means scale image to fit in a box of that size, preserving aspect ratio), the `-a` parameter should be used with rsvg.

Comment: This mangled my images, all sorts of weird artifacts.  inkscape did a better job.

Comment: Be warned, `brew install rsvg` on OSX installs a million things - GDK, OpenSSL, Python, etc.

Comment: FYI, the current install command is `brew install librsvg` and the conversion command is `rsvg-convert`.

Comment: I found librsvg (or `rsvg-convert` in case of Arch) to give the best and most consistent results when converting complicated svgs to png. Follow up with `optipng` to reduce output file size.

Comment: In Ubuntu: `sudo apt install librsvg2-bin; rsvg-convert input.svg -o output.png`

Comment: I had success with rsvg-convert 2.4.20 on Windows.

Comment: After doing some performance testing across various ways of converting SVGs to PNGs, `rsvg-convert` is also the fastest I have found by far (much faster than Puppeteer with Chromium, Playwright with Chromium, ImageMagick, Inkscape and SVG.NET at least)

Comment: Simple is the best, this worked so smoothly compared to all the answers above it:)

Comment: Does not work for me. The size argument is not respected

Comment: `convert -background transparent -gravity center -resize 64x64 -extent 64x64 supercloud.svg supercloud.png`

Answer (score 61):

If you are on MacOS X and having problems with Imagemagick's convert, you might try reinstalling it with RSVG lib.
Using HomeBrew:

```bash
brew remove imagemagick
brew install imagemagick --with-librsvg
```

Verify that it's delegating correctly:

```
$ convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-8 Q16 x86_64 2014-12-17 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC Modules
Delegates: bzlib cairo fontconfig freetype jng jpeg lcms ltdl lzma png rsvg tiff xml zlib
```

It should display `rsvg`.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Specifically I ran `convert ic_comment_48px.svg -size 30x30 ic_comment_30px.png` and the output image is 48 x 48. Made sure that imagemagick is delegating to rsvg as you've explained.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me - the default `convert` did convert svg to png, but the results were hopeless; after reinstalling, they're perfect. Also, conversion is significantly faster.

Comment: This worked me on Mac OSX. I don't find the new conversion faster, but much much more accurate. I highly recommend all Mac OSX users give this a try.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, oh well. Thank you, worked like a charm, and I never would have known to take these steps otherwise

Comment: This answer still helps a lot, also unter OSX high sierra.

Comment: On mojave i get `invalid option: --with-librsvg`

Comment: @zaitsman Probably too late, but...
The argument option has changed, try with `--with-rsvg`. And I think it needs the `librsvg2-bin` package to be installed.
See https://gist.github.com/maxivak/1476f7e979879da9f75371a86d5627b5

Comment: ImageMagick utilizes [inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) if it's in your execution path, otherwise [RSVG](http://developer.gnome.org/rsvg/). If neither are available, ImageMagick reverts to its internal SVG renderer. The default resolution is 96 DPI. Use [-size](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#size) command line option to specify the maximum width and height. If you want to render a very large SVG and you trust the source, enable this option: `-define svg:xml-parse-huge=true`.

Answer (score 23):

After following the steps in [Jose Alban's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27524633), I was able to get ImageMagick to work just fine using the following command:

```bash
convert -density 1536 -background none -resize 100x100 input.svg output-100.png
```

The number 1536 comes from a ballpark estimate of density, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41765568/2063546) for more information.

Comment: use `-size` instead, apparently in some IM version resize makes image blurry

Answer (score 20):

In ImageMagick, one gets a better SVG rendering if one uses Inkscape or RSVG with ImageMagick than its own internal MSVG/XML rendered. RSVG is a delegate that needs to be installed with ImageMagick. If Inkscape is installed on the system, ImageMagick will use it automatically. I use Inkscape in ImageMagick below.

There is no "magic" parameter that will do what you want.

But, one can compute very simply the exact density needed to render the output.

Here is a small 50x50 button when rendered at the default density of 96:

```bash
convert button.svg button1.png
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Suppose we want the output to be 500. The input is 50 at default density of 96 (older versions of Inkscape may be using 92). So you can compute the needed density in proportion to the ratios of the dimensions and the densities.

```
512/50 = X/96
X = 96*512/50 = 983
```

```bash
convert -density 983 button.svg button2.png
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

In ImageMagick 7, you can do the computation in-line as follows:

```
magick -density "%[fx:96*512/50]" button.svg button3.png

or

in_size=50
in_density=96
out_size=512

magick -density "%[fx:$in_density*$out_size/$in_size]" button.svg button3.png
```

Comment: +1 for the magical fx expression which avoids a separate command, or use of a calculator. As a side note, if you run `identify -format "%x x %y (%w x %h) file.svg`, you will also get the width and height for the default density in the output (which you need for $in_size in the formula)!

Comment: you can do it even in 1 line https://stackoverflow.com/a/66901038/1597158

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm! and if you add the option `-background none` you'll also have a .png with transparent background!

Answer (score 18):

In order to rescale the image, the option `-density` should be used. As far as I know the standard density is 72 and maps the size 1:1. If you want the output png to be twice as big as the original svg, set the density to 72*2=144:

```bash
convert -density 144 source.svg target.png
```

Comment: Note that convert options have to be *before* the input file.  I.e. `convert source.svg -density 144 target.png` won't rescale the image.

Comment: Actually the standard density seems to be 90. So it would be `convert -density 180 source.svg target.png`

Answer (score 18):

On macOS using brew, using librsvg directly works well

```bash
brew install librsvg
rsvg-convert test.svg -o test.png
```

Many options are available via `rsvg-convert --help`

Answer (score 11):

For simple SVG to PNG conversion I found cairosvg (https://cairosvg.org/) performs better than ImageMagick. Steps for install and running on all SVG files in your directory.

```bash
pip3 install cairosvg
```

Open a python shell in the directory which contains your .svg files and run:

```py
import os
import cairosvg

for file in os.listdir('.'):
    name = file.split('.svg')[0]
    cairosvg.svg2png(url=name+'.svg',write_to=name+'.png')
```

This will also ensure you don't overwrite your original .svg files, but will keep the same name. You can then move all your .png files to another directory with:

```
$ mv *.png [new directory]
```

Comment: crashed for me on windows 10:
    import cairocffi as cairo
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cairo = dlopen(ffi, 'cairo', 'cairo-2', 'cairo-gobject-2', 'cairo.so.2')
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 36, in dlopen
    raise OSError("dlopen() failed to load a library: %s" % ' / '.join(names))
OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2 / cairo-gobject-2 / cairo.so.2

Comment: Nice, `cairosvg` on Ubuntu-19.04 did the job for me.

Comment: I just wanted to write: What an excellent solution! The first PNGs looked great, but others didn't. Instead I have to write: It completely depends on the SVG which solution offers the best quality.

Comment: `cairosvg` worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 instances (WSL and Gcloud free tier VM). From a base image, I had to `sudo apt install python3-pip`, followed by the `pip3 install cairosvg` command above. From there, I was able to use the command line executable from `~/.local/bin/cairosvg`.

Answer (score 8):

why don't you give a try to inkscape command line, this is my bat file to convert all svg in this dir to png:

> FOR %%x IN (*.svg)  DO   C:\Ink\App\Inkscape\inkscape.exe  %%x  -z --export-dpi=500 --export-area-drawing --export-png="%%~nx.png"

Answer (score 8):

### This is what worked for me and would be the easiest to run.

```sh
find . -type f -name "*.svg" -exec bash -c 'rsvg-convert -h 1000  $0 > $0.png' {} \;
rename 's/svg\.png/png/' *
```

This will loop all the files in your current folder and sub folder and look for `.svg` files and will convert it to png with transparent background.

Make sure you have installed the librsvg and rename util

```sh
brew install librsvg
brew install rename
```

Answer (score 6):

Transparent background, exported at target height/size using ImageMagick 7:

```bash
magick -background none -size x1080 in.svg out.png
```

One-liner mass converter:

```
for i in *svg; do magick -background none -size x1080 "$i" "${i%svg}png"; done
```

Comment: I'm surprised this answer is so low. Some of the other approaches drew my complicated SVG incorrectly, but this worked perfectly.

Comment: I had to use `convert`, but otherwise it worked perfectly (`convert -background none -size x1080 in.svg out.png`).

Answer (score 5):

I came to this post - but I just wanted to do the conversion by batch and quick without the usage of any parameters (due to several files with different sizes).

```bash
rsvg drawing.svg drawing.png
```

For me the requirements were probably a bit easier than for the original author. (Wanted to use SVGs in MS PowerPoint, but it doesn't allow)

Comment: For reference, on macOS this is installed with `brew install librsvg` and the conversion command is `rsvg-convert`.

Comment: in Ubutni it is rsvg-convert too,package is librsvg2-bin  and the output needs -o drawing.png

Answer (score 5):

Without librsvg, you may get a black png/jpeg image. We have to install `librsvg` to `convert` svg file with imagemagick.

## Ubuntu

```bash
sudo apt-get install imagemagick librsvg
convert -density 1200 test.svg test.png
```

## MacOS

```bash
brew install imagemagick librsvg
convert -density 1200 test.svg test.png
```

Comment: I don't have this library installed and I don't get black images either.

Answer (score 4):

One thing that just bit me was setting the `-density` AFTER the input file name. That didn't work. Moving it to the first option in convert (before anything else) made it work (for me, YMMV, etc).

Answer (score 2):

On Linux with Inkscape 1.0 to convert from svg to png need to use

```bash
inkscape -w 1024 -h 1024 input.svg --export-file output.png
```

not

```bash
inkscape -w 1024 -h 1024 input.svg --export-filename output.png
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this issue through changing the `width` and `height` attributes of the `<svg>` tag to match my intended output size and then converting it using ImageMagick. Works like a charm.

Here's my Python code, a function that will return the JPG file's content:

```py
import gzip, re, os
from ynlib.files import ReadFromFile, WriteToFile
from ynlib.system import Execute
from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString


def SVGToJPGInMemory(svgPath, newWidth, backgroundColor):

    tempPath = os.path.join(self.rootFolder, 'data')
    fileNameRoot = 'temp_' + str(image.getID())

    if svgPath.lower().endswith('svgz'):
        svg = gzip.open(svgPath, 'rb').read()
    else:
        svg = ReadFromFile(svgPath)

    xmldoc = parseString(svg)

    width = float(xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].attributes['width'].value.split('px')[0])
    height = float(xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].attributes['height'].value.split('px')[0])

    newHeight = int(newWidth / width * height) 

    xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].attributes['width'].value = '%spx' % newWidth
    xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].attributes['height'].value = '%spx' % newHeight

    WriteToFile(os.path.join(tempPath, fileNameRoot + '.svg'), xmldoc.toxml())
    Execute('convert -background "%s" %s %s' % (backgroundColor, os.path.join(tempPath, fileNameRoot + '.svg'), os.path.join(tempPath, fileNameRoot + '.jpg')))

    jpg = open(os.path.join(tempPath, fileNameRoot + '.jpg'), 'rb').read()

    os.remove(os.path.join(tempPath, fileNameRoot + '.jpg'))
    os.remove(os.path.join(tempPath, fileNameRoot + '.svg'))

    return jpg
```

Comment: why would you return a computer generated image as jpeg :(?

Answer (score 1):

The top answer by @808sound did not work for me. I wanted to resize
[image: Kenney.nl UI Pack]

and got
[image: Kenney UI Pack messed up]

So instead I opened up Inkscape, then went to `File`, `Export as PNG file`and a GUI box popped up that allowed me to set the exact dimensions I needed.

Version on `Ubuntu 16.04 Linux`: 
`Inkscape 0.91 (September 2016)`

(This image is from [Kenney.nl's asset packs](http://kenney.nl/assets) by the way)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting "low poly" curves using the general approach of increasing the density. So I decided to dig a little deeper and solve that problem as it seemed to be a side effect of this approach and I think it has to do with the original density or dpi.

We have seen 72 in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15997811/7573223) and 96 in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57512918/7573223) being suggested as the default density of an image, but which one? what if mine is different?

ImageMagick has a way to sort that out:

```
identify -verbose test.svg
```

this will put out a lot of metadata about the image file, including:

```
Image:
  Filename: test.svg
  Format: SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics)
  Mime type: image/svg+xml
  Class: ...
  Geometry: ...
  Resolution: 37.79x37.79
  Print size: ...
  Units: PixelsPerCentimeter
  # and a whole lot MORE ...
```

for a more concise query you can try:

```
identify -format "%x x %y %U" test.svg
=> 37.789999999999999147 x 37.789999999999999147 PixelsPerCentimeter
```

as suggested by [this forum post](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?p=58180#p58180) and modified with this [documentation](https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php)

Now we know the current density of the image but may need to convert it to the correct units for conversion or mogrifying (PixelsPerInch or dpi)

this is a simple calculations of PixelsPerCentimeter x 2.54

```
37.789999999999999147 x 2.54 = 95.9866 ~> 96
```

if you prefer a chart or online calculator for this you can try https://www.pixelto.net/cm-to-px-converter.

now that we have the right original density converted to dpi, the rest of the logic stated in the above answers falls into place and the svg file can be scaled to a better "resolution" by multiplying the original density.

the original density was far too pixelated as a png for me, so in my case 5x the original density or `-density 480` was good enough for me.  Remember that this resizes the image as well and you will need to adjust for that when using / implementing the image as compared to the original svg.

NOTE: I did try the Inkscape approaches as well and also had the pixelation problem, but had already seen an improvement with the density approach so I decided to dig into that deeper.  The output of the Inkscape attempt however gave me the idea, which you can also use for determining the dpi, but that is a lot to install just to get something you can already get with ImageMagick

```
Area 0:0:20.75:17 exported to 21 x 17 pixels (96 dpi)
```