# nodejs imagemagick converting svg to png adds a white background, how to keep it transparent?

Tags: node.js, svg, node-imagemagick

I'm trying to use imagemagick to convert svgs to pngs, rescale them and put them in a response stream.

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemagick like this:

```
var imageUri = __dirname + '/images/' + project + '/' + image + '.svg';

console.log(imageUri);

var svg = fs.readFileSync(imageUri, 'utf8');
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png' });

var size = '' + (100 * scale);

var conv = im.convert(['svg:-', '-resize', size + 'x' + size, 'png:-']);
conv.on('data', function(data) {
    res.write(data, 'binary');
}); 
conv.on('end', function() {
    res.end();
});                                                                                
conv.stdin.write(svg);
conv.stdin.end();
```

Only problem is that it adds a background when I was hoping for something transparent. Any ideas of how I can fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853325/how-to-convert-a-svg-to-a-png-with-image-magick

just exec this code : convert -density 1200 -resize 200x200 source.svg target.png

Comment: of course, after this send and unlink created file

Comment: and -background none, as sayed in link

Comment: That answer and question is a command line way of doing it. I'm doing it in a constantly running app.

Comment: yep, but image magick more powerfull in command line. So, your code do the same, just by library around real commands.

Comment: maybe it is, but I'm asking how to do this in node.js because I have to clue how to make console commands to serve get requests.

Comment: Try adding `-background none`

Comment: @MarkSetchell doesn't work :(