# Convert SVG to PNG inside Web Worker

Tags: javascript, svg, web-worker

I would like to convert an SVG to a PNG inside a Web Worker.
My problem is, that the DOM is not accessible from within the Worker,
so I cannot draw the SVG to a canvas or something like that.

Comment: Perhaps you can leverage Inkscape or ImageMagick? (I've not had occasion to play with web-workers) Provided you get a full-calorie executable environment, you can use either of the two above sugestions. For more, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853325/how-to-convert-a-svg-to-a-png-with-image-magick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [thumbo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/thumbo)

```
import Thumbo, { Transfer } from "thumbo";

Thumbo.init().then(async () => {
  Thumbo.thumbnail(
    Transfer(await (await fetch("/path/to/img.svg")).arrayBuffer()),
    Thumbo.ImageFormat.Svg,
    20,
    20
  ).then((thumbnailBuffer) => {
    document.getElementById("img1").src = URL.createObjectURL(
      new Blob([thumbnailBuffer])
    );
  });

  Thumbo.thumbnailFromUrl(
    "https://example.com/image.svg",
    Thumbo.ImageFormat.Svg,
    20,
    20
  ).then((thumbnailBuffer) => {
    document.getElementById("img2").src = URL.createObjectURL(
      new Blob([thumbnailBuffer])
    );
  });
});
```

Under the hood, thumbo uses Rust's *tiny_skia* & *resvg* libraries compiled to a Web Assembly module, to render SVG in a web worker and convert it to PNG. See [thumbo-core](https://github.com/ahkohd/thumbo-core), [thumbo](https://github.com/ahkohd/thumbo)

[Demo ▶️](https://thumbo.netlify.app/)
[Source code](https://github.com/ahkohd/thumbo/blob/main/example/src/js/demo.js)

PS: I'm the author of thumbo

Comment: Thanks I am going to try this today I'll reach out to you

Answer (score 2):

Weeell, you can always manually parse the SVG and build a bitmap from that, but (!) it's a tad more work obviously as you'd have to build a SVG parser as well as a PNG writer, not to mention rasterizing code for lines and two-modes polygon fill incl. anti-aliasing, pattern, matrix, composition, blending and gradient support. Could be a nice weekend project though :)

On a more serious note though: you can only do this with the built-in tools using regular context (none-webworker) or optionally set up a server based service.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am setting up a web service. It just would have been a smoother solution to do the conversion directly on a second thread, because I will be drawing the exact same SVG in various scales.

Comment: @ChristophBühler why do you need the png version ? svg does scale pretty well ;-) (even on canvas)

Comment: @Kaiido The SVGs are quite huge (20mb) and the images have to appear quickly. This is why I write a canvas buffer.

Comment: ouch! a 20mb svg oO. But once loaded into an `<img>` you should still be able to draw it as fast as a any one, at any scale on a canvas.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. However, the process of putting an SVG onto an Image is crazy expensive.. I will test a few things and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not intend to support the creation of `ImageBitmap` in service workers starting from an SVG blob: https://issues.chromium.org/issues/41250699

If you need to do this in a Web Extension, you can use the [`chrome.offscreen` API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/offscreen) and use the DOM as you normally would on a web page.