# DOMException when tried to call createImageBitmap() with Blob

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying ro create image bitmap from svg string in worker with following code:

```
const svg = `<svg width="400" height="110">
    <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
  </svg>`;
const blob = new Blob([svg], { type: 'image/svg+xml' });
const imageBitmap = await createImageBitmap(blob);
```

But have a DOMException on last line:
1. In Chrome with no message
2. In Mozilla with message "An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable"

Help please, I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert SVG to PNG inside Web Worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36713054/convert-svg-to-png-inside-web-worker)