# Convert SVG to transparent PNG using Carrierwave & MiniMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, carrierwave, minimagick

I want to convert an SVG to a transparent PNG using the following MiniMagick command on a Carrierwave upload:

```
convert input.svg -transparent white output.png
```

How can I achieve that? Please provide FULL-EXAMPLE

Comment: This place isn't for tell me how to do x. You're supposed to have tried some stuff and need additional help. You tagged a few libraries that can do this. You just need to specify those settings on your uploader for carrierwave.

Comment: Use https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-create-a-thumbnail-with-both-color-and-grayscale-versions-in-one-image as inspiration

Comment: I didn't add an example to keep the question brief. Please see what I have already tried here: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/2440

Answer (score 1):

I [have read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853325/how-to-convert-a-svg-to-a-png-with-imagemagick) that convert options have to be **before** the input file. Try with

```rb
MiniMagick::Tool::Convert.new do |convert|
  convert << "-density" << "72" 
  convert << "-transparent" << "white"
  convert << "input.svg"
  convert << "output.png"
end
```