# Android 11: Will not show the xml icon of my app

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out why a generic android icon appears for my app in newer Android versions.

My icon is defined as a .xml file.

There is a LIne in my Android Manifest that reads this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
```

Android studio even shows me a picture of the icon in the side bar.

If I try to launch (USB Debug) my app on an older phone (Android 8) the icon shows just fine (I'm talkinga bout the app icon in where you are browsing you installed apps)

If I try to launch it in my new phone (Android 11) I get the green background generic Icon with the little alien that is the android logo, I think.

How can I get newer phones to show the proper Icon?

Comment: You might need to switch to PNG or WebP and away from whatever sort of XML-defined drawable (e.g., vector drawable) that you are using.

Comment: I don't really remember how I created the XML originally. Is there a way that I can convert the XML to a PNG. I don't even know how to open the file other than with a text editor

Comment: If you open it in Android Studio, you may be able to get a preview of the image, which you can then download or screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I got it. Thanks @CommonsWare

I had to creeate PNG versions (different sizes) for the image. So first I used shapeshifter.design website to convert the XML to an SVG and then I used the answer here: [How to convert a SVG to a PNG with ImageMagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853325/how-to-convert-a-svg-to-a-png-with-imagemagick)

To write a scritp that would convert the SVG to the different sizes required.

I wrote those requirements here as a PHP array (part of my script). I used PHP because It's my prefer "write a quick script" laanguage:

```
$SIZES = [
   "mipmap-hdpi"      => 72,
   "mipmap-mdpi"      => 48,   
   "mipmap-xhdpi"     => 96,  
   "mipmap-xxhdpi"    => 144,   
   "mipmap-xxxhdpi"   => 192       
];
```

For those that don't know the left hand side of the "=>" is the key of the array and the name of the idrectory inside app/src/main/res folder of the project directory. The right hand side is the size. The launcher icons are all squares.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try to reboot your new device? I have already experienced that Android has similar problems as Windows with its icon cache...

Comment: Yes, Ive tried rebooting it several times for an unrelated matter

Comment: @aarelovich Did you name two **different** icons `app_icon` one after the other? 
Same effect with an arbitrary png icon? You have probably already tried to uninstall the app on the new device before reinstalling ... Do you have a special launcher on your new device?

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by one after the other. I don't think I have any other icons with hta name. And no, I don't have a special launcher

Comment: @aarelovich I meant: Did you compile the app first with a temporary icon named "app-icon" and then later replace the temporary icon with the final icon with the same name, so that only the resources have changed, but not the code?
It is difficult to guess the cause without having the device next to you and knowing what you have already tried. We can only guess. 
Last idea: Try to install the "Hello World" program with your icon on the new device, then at least you will know if your app or the Android of the new device is the cause.

Comment: Thank you for your time but I found that I sovled it useing PNGs

Comment:  ... as I suggested in my second last post.