# Echo the contents of a paragraph into a file without any modifications to the paragraph?

Tags: windows, batch-file, key

How do i echo a paragraph into a file without doing any kind of manipulation to the paragraph.
i mean newline,space,special characters etc and all the indentation should be same.

My .bat file(containing  the contents of .ppk file)

```
    echo (PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: none
Comment: rsa-key-20130127
Public-Lines: 6
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQBVYEVYbGluh1Ne6psUMsK4TRiqwN8GG+ImbsfC
qIYje3S7n3owtEUSDMEc5VvTZTEXk/CKHK6tXhGSNrExXKDhKE2HejY7TFtbc3vU
KM4OogxYeZs/0yBX/kVEu5+kIeZ0ZEsq/ve9/hnEVLZ3DFotUoDzzwdd4jAHUZv2
08xk5tTxodh+iO26RVPSaklZrFjbZkqCwPOnVZhK6JqE/7kZyIM+p5W8CH8XPG3r
fgU/R4BpwMNz+pYo2iiV3eZApI25lY+IcjclA5Amx1JdCM1zIvA6C8ABUbTMXsyG
RHkzdEYjw5+pBF8qLU8s8+M9sw0l5z58dP9t+vuYWz+JrsmL
Private-Lines: 14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Private-MAC: 2e75877ab827b492b2a0a16c5019cd45f96e4990) > myfile.txt
```

The above line does not work after i save it as .bat and execute

i want to put the paragraph in a file with a unique name so that it does not overwrite any existing file.
Do i need to echo at each and every line and keep appending.

Comment: You don't need to use an echo at each line if you add a `^` as the last character on each line, as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015163/heredoc-for-windows-batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a unique text marker after the final EXIT /B, followed by your paragraph. Use FOR /F with FINDSTR to locate the unique marker, and then use a FOR /F loop to process all the lines after the marker.

There are many variations, each with different limitations.

Here is the simplest form, but it also has the most limitations. The limitations are described in the text.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "skip="
for /f "delims=:" %%N in (
  'findstr /x /n ":::BeginText" "%~f0"'
) do if not defined skip set skip=%%N
>test.txt (
  for /f "usebackq skip=%skip% delims=" %%A in ("%~f0") do echo(%%A
)
type test.txt
exit /b

:::BeginText
This text will be exactly preserved with the following limitations:

  1) Each line will be terminated by CR LF even if original has only LF.

  2) Lines are limited in length to approximately 8191 bytes.

  3) Empty lines will be stripped.

; 4) Lines beginning with ; will be stripped.

  5) The text will be truncated at the first occurance of hex code 0x1A (Ctrl-Z).

Special characters like ^ & < > | etc. do not cause a problem
```

Some odd FOR /F option syntax removes the limitation on lines beginning with `;`

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "skip="
for /f "delims=:" %%N in (
  'findstr /x /n ":::BeginText" "%~f0"'
) do if not defined skip set skip=%%N
>test.txt (
  for /f ^usebackq^ skip^=%skip%^ delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ("%~f0") do echo(%%A
)
type test.txt
exit /b

:::BeginText
This text will be exactly preserved with the following limitations:

  1) Each line will be terminated by CR LF even if original has only LF.

  2) Lines are limited in length to approximately 8191 bytes.

  3) Empty lines will be stripped.

  4) The text will be truncated at the first occurance of hex code 0x1A (Ctrl-Z).

Special characters like ^ & < > | etc. do not cause a problem
;Lines beginning with ; are preserved
```

Reading FINDSTR /N output instead of reading the file directly preserves empty lines. But a new limitation with leading `:` is introduced.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "skip="
for /f "delims=:" %%N in (
  'findstr /x /n ":::BeginText" "%~f0"'
) do if not defined skip set skip=%%N
>test.txt (
  for /f "skip=%skip% tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in (
   'findstr /n "^" "%~f0"'
  ) do echo(%%B
)
type test.txt
exit /b

:::BeginText
This text will be exactly preserved with the following limitations:

  1) Each line will be terminated by CR LF even if original has only LF.

  2) Lines are limited in length to approximately 8191 bytes.

:::  3) Leading : will be stripped from each line.

Special characters like ^ & < > | etc. do not cause a problem
Empty lines are preserved!
;Lines beginning with ; are preserved.
```

This final version is about as good as it gets. Delayed expansion must be toggled on and off to preserve `!` that may appear in the text.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "skip="
for /f "delims=:" %%N in (
  'findstr /x /n ":::BeginText" "%~f0"'
) do if not defined skip set skip=%%N
>test.txt (
  for /f "skip=%skip% tokens=*" %%A in (
   'findstr /n "^" "%~f0"'
  ) do (
    set "line=%%A"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!line:*:=!
    endlocal
  )
)
type test.txt
exit /b

:::BeginText
This text will be exactly preserved with the following limitations:

  1) Each line will be terminated by CR LF even if original has only LF.

  2) Lines are limited in length to approximately 8191 bytes.

Special characters like ^ & < > | etc. do not cause a problem.
Empty lines are preserved!
;Lines beginning with ; are preserved.
:::Leading : are preserved.
```