# Create a HTML page displaying GIFs with a Batch File

Tags: html, batch-file, gif

I need to display a lot of GIF pictures in one place, and being able to add some whenever I want. 
The solution I have found is to create a batch file which creates an HTML page displaying the GIF. But I'm a beginner with CMD language and after some research here is what I have written :

```
FOR /F %%G IN ('dir /B *.gif') DO echo ^<img src="%%G"^>^ ^<br^>^<br^>^<br^> >> gifs.html
```

It works but it is really simple, and I don't seem to be able to add page settings and layout (such as center the GIFs, maybe add a background etc...) automatically from the Batch. I can't find anything on the web as to how to do that. Can someone put me on the rails here ?

Thanks very much !!

Djokito

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27652107/1683264) useful.  Just sayin'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create separate static CSS file (named e.g.: your.css) in the same folder containing something like:

```
body{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
}

img{
  width: 300px;
}
```

and then add this line to the beginning of your batch file:

```
echo ^<link type="text/css" href="your.css"^> >> gifs.html
```

Comment: That's exactly the type of answer I was expecting ! Thanks, gonna try it right now ! Quick question, if I write multiple lines in my batch file ending in ">> gifs.html", it will add the lines after the other in the html doc ?

Comment: Ok it worked great, I just had to add "rel="stylesheet"" in the code to make it work ! Thanks :)