# Error in Batchfile, Won't Run Further Than A Certain Part In the Code (BATCH)

Tags: batch-file

which you can download here since it's too big to put here: https://www.mediafire.com/?vks3a3fwhbj4nay won't go further than the code that rojo posted on my question here: [Get A Batch Error When Running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431319/get-a-batch-error-when-running)?

P.S Please don't tell me ways I can improve my code, I know it's messy and I did't loop some stuff and the login system is kinda screwed but I'm still just starting batch coding

EDIT: TO REPRODUCE THE PROBLEM FIRST TYPE skip AND PRESS ENTER THEN TYPE startx AND PRESS ENTER THEN TYPE IN AS USER:Cool841555 and PASS:somerandompassthatidontusesincethisisgonnabeuploadedto

Comment: 1. What does it display before it stops? 2. privatepaste.com or pastebin.com would be a better choice for the code link. 3. What exactly should one type after starting the batch file to reproduce the problem?

Comment: sorry i totally forgot about that id better change the link and it doesnt display anything it just closes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
:end_welcome

goto :EOF
```

to

```
:end_welcome

goto :MENU
```