# ECHO lines of code from batch file

Tags: batch-file

Is it possible to create simple code such as JAVA or XML in batch file?  I am trying below code but the file is not created.

```
@ECHO off
(   
echo  public class Main {
echo public static void main(String[] args) {
echo    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
echo    }
echo }
) > text.java

pause
```

Comment: Sure it is possible, but you have to make sure that you get the syntax right.

Comment: You have to escape batch special characters with `^` so `(` becomes `^(`. Trying to do XML will be very ugly as all `<>` need to be escaped.

Comment: @Noodles It's not `(` left parenthesis but `)` right one causing problems inside a  `(parenthesized command block)`

Comment: OP, you should also consider a [batch script heredoc function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15032476/1683264).  Then you won't have to worry about escaping parentheses or XML tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [escape](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) all occurrences of `)` right parenthesis in `echo` commands inside a parenthesized command block as follows:

```
@ECHO off
(   
echo  public class Main {
echo public static void main(String[] args^) {
echo    System.out.println("Hello, World!"^);
echo    }
echo }
) > text.java

pause
```

Comment: In this case, yes - all `)`. But it should not be escaped if it is quoted.

Answer (score 0):

First, off, as a general rule **when debugging batch files always remove the `echo off` line from the top of your batch**.  CMD is trying to tell you what the problem is and that first line is suppressing all debug information.

In this case, running without suppressing debug information shows you that your `main` line is causing a syntax error.

> echo public static void main(String[] args) {
>
> { was unexpected at this time.

The error is that certain characters are being interpreted as a special character in the batch file.  The way to escape a character in batch is with the caret (`^`).  Adding them to all of the special characters in that line causes `echo` to produce the correct output.

```
echo public static void main^(String^[^] args^) ^{
```

Not all of these escape characters are strictly necessary, but if you're unfamiliar with batch then it can be hard to tell which.  The easiest and safest fix is to add an escape before any special character.

There are other syntax errors in your batch.  You can continue running your batch with error messages enabled, and fix the remainder the same way.

Comment: The `{` character is **not** being interpreted as a special character in a batch file. Show an example to proof that I'm wrong, please.

Comment: @JosefZ You are correct.  The curly brace is the symptom.  The rparen is the cause.  The error message isn't clear, though, and escaping both does no harm.

Comment: Then. why don't you advise escaping _all_ characters , e.g. `echo  ^p^u^b^l^i^c^ ^c^l^a^s^s^ ^M^a^i^n^ ^{`?

Comment: Because I'm not intentionally being a pedantic jackass. Honestly, what more are you looking for here? I already admitted that your answer is technically correct (the best kind of correct). I even upvoted your answer. For someone versed in the idiosyncracies of the cmd parser, it is useful to know exactly when it's necessary to escape an rparen or a quote or a bracket, and when it's not necessary. For somebody who just wants to write a simple batch file to emit some text, the much simpler rule is to escape all symbols.

Comment: IMHO your answer confuse the OP more than supposedly aids him. I imagine the OP escaping _all special characters_ in the Batch files he write from now on just because you suggested that... **`:/`** If _you_ don't know which characters must be escaped and in which cases, then you should not posted an answer (and the same point apply to any other question about any other topic: people that don't know the topic should not post answers).