# powershell in batch file result as variable

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to call a powershell script from a batch file.

I have the following

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (
    'PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "(@(Select-String %QUERY% %FILE% -Context 0, 1 | % {$_.Context.PostContext} ))"'
) do set RESULT=%%a

echo %RESULT%
```

But the `%RESULT%` is printing the whole command not the result.

All I'm trying to do is read a file for a flag and then return the next line as the `%RESULT%`

I ran the following from command line

```
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "& (Select-String FAILED e:\path\to\app.log -Context 0, 1 | % {$_.Context.PostContext} )"
```

and got this

```
& : The term ':generic/generic.k4.csv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ & (Select-String FAILED e:\path\to\app.log -Context 0 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:generic/generic.k4.csv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your first block of code is the use of the `usebackq` token, while still wrapping the command in single quotes, forcing the command to be interpreted as a literal string (which is then being put into `%RESULT%`).  From `for /?`

> usebackq    - specifies that the new semantics are in force,
>                     where a back quoted string is executed as a
>                     command and a single quoted string is a
>                     literal string command and allows the use of
>                     double quotes to quote file names in
>                     file-set.

**To fix this, either wrap the command in backticks (`` ` ``) instead of single quotes (`'`), or remove the `usebackq` token from your command.**

The second PowerShell block does not do the same thing as the first.  The syntax `& (expr)` evaluates the expression inside the parentheses and then tries to execute it.  In this case, your `Select-String` is being evaluated, and returning the selected line.  **PowerShell is trying to execute the extracted line as if it's a command.  This is probably not what you want.**

*For further analysis, please provide more explanation about what you expected to happen here, along with an example of the contents of app.log.*

Comment: He's also got to escape the pipe with `^|`.

Comment: @SomethingDark Normally I'd agree, but when I ran the command it executed correctly without escaping the pipe.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I've been [rebuked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35962454/35962630#comment59585741_35962630) for suggesting somebody escape a character that wasn't strictly required by the parser, so I'm not about to suggest it again unless I'm certain the code won't work without it.

Comment: Weird; pipes usually break `for` loops. Must be because it's inside quotes with `usebackq`.

Comment: @SomethingDark - From a CMD.EXE FOR /F perspective, the pipe must be either quoted, or escaped, but not both. The pipe is within a quoted string, so it should not be escaped.

Comment: ... but the single percent-sign in this part: `-Context 0, 1 | % {$_.Context.PostContext}` must be doubled this way: `-Context 0, 1 | %% {$_.Context.PostContext}`

Comment: Good catch, @Aacini.  I think it's better in this case to change the percent sign to the PS keyword `foreach`, which is more explicit and doesn't have any issues with escaping.