# How to embed a text file in a Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to create a batch file that writes a text file (possibly including variables). In Unix with bash this is trivial:

```
#!/bin/bash
ver="1.2.3"
cat > file.txt <<EOL
line 1, ${ver}
line 2 
line 3
... 
EOL
```

What is the simplest way to do this with a batch file?

Note: there is a complete solution using an 'heredoc' routine at [heredoc for Windows batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015163/heredoc-for-windows-batch) but it seems too complex for ad-hoc use. I'm looking for a quick and simple way.

Comment: Type in the batch file.

Comment: @SomethingDark - thanks, I tried to find it and could not. The heredoc is pretty complete though much more complex for ad-hoc cases. I found some other questions but I could not add the suggested answer to them so I opened a new one. Should I delete this?

Comment: It's up to you, really. Personally, I would, but at the same time if we deleted all the batch questions that were duplicates of existing batch questions, there wouldn't have been any questions asked in 2016.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The follwoing works fine, if there is just one block of data (text)

```
@ECHO OFF
set string=beautyful
REM get linenumber for Data:
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n /b "REM StartData" "%~f0"') do set ln=%%a

REM print Data (use call to parse the line and evaluate variables):
(for /f "usebackq skip=%ln% delims=" %%a in ("%~f0") do call echo %%a)>"new.txt"
type "new.txt"
goto :eof

REM StartData
hello %string% world
line 2
line 3
```

If you don't have variables in the data, omit the `call`. Advantage: no need to escape anything. Even usually poisonous characters work (instead of the `for` loop, you can also just use `more +%ln% "%~f0"`). Sadly, you loose this advantage, when you use `call` to parse the lines for variables.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and least messy way I found is as follows:

```
set ver=1.2.3
(
echo ^
line 1, %ver%^

line 2^

line 3^

...
) > file.txt
```

Running the script I get:

```
C:\> type file.txt
line 1, 1.2.3
line 2
line 3
...
```

Basically, each line must be terminated with a caret (^) and an empty line.

Comment: Not understanding why you are escaping the line feed?

Comment: @Squashman because I want to use just one echo so the caret is not used as an escape but as a continuation