# How to create a file in windows using command prompt with some multi-line text?

Tags: windows, cmd

Is there a way to create a file with some multi-line text in windows using command prompt only?

I am trying to create a file in windows using command prompt with some multi-line text. I have tried using echo, type but they are only storing first line of text in the newly created file.

```
line1 = 'KT p:CN=sapserv2, OU=SAProuter, O=SAP Trust Community II, C=DE 192.168.0.76\n# SNC-connection from SAP to local system for R/3-Support\nP 192.168.0.16 192.168.0.76 3299\nD * * *'

echo line1 > file1.txt
```

I am expecting a file with multi-line text using only command prompt.

Comment: Cmd's `echo` doesn't understand `\n` (or similar controls). It handles it very literally as a `\` and a `n`.

Comment: See also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54609804)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(echo Line1 & echo.Line2 & echo.Line3) > file
```