# C# Console and .bat instructions

Tags: c#, batch-file

I am writing a Console application that will work with a set of instructions.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cmd = "";
        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            cmd = args[0];
        }
        switch (cmd)
        {
            case "SSHPPK":
                InitPpk(InitCompleted, args); //Read from args
                break;
            case "SSHPWD":
                InitPwd(InitCompleted, args); //Read from args
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Command");
                break;
        }
    }

    private static void InitCompleted(ConnectInstructions instructions)
    {
        //Read next lines from .bat file and execute untill the end  (Psuedo, While not at end of file)
        //Get command
        //Get server IP
        if (instructions.ConnectType == "SSHPPK")
        {
            //Connect using Private Key
        }
        else if (instructions.ConnectType == "SSHPWD")
        {
            //Connect using Password
        }
        //Get Root
        //Do update
    }

    private static void InitPwd(Action<ConnectInstructions> action, string[] args)
    {
    }

    private static void InitPpk(Action<ConnectInstructions> action, string[] args)
    {

    }
}
```

The batch file I am using will look something like this

```
SSHUpdate.exe "SSHPWD" "Username" "Password"
update [Server1 IP] /var/root/site
update [Server2 IP] /var/root/site
update [Server3 IP] /var/root/site
update [Server4 IP] /var/root/siteA
update [Server4 IP] /var/root/siteB
```

And when I run the .bat file it opens SSHUpdate.exe and I can connect using the args, But I am unable to access the rest of the lines from the same process

**All Servers will use the same password or private key**

Currently I am doing it like the following
SSHUpdate.exe "SSHPWD" "Username" "Password" "Instruction File" where the Instruction File contains the instructions

Should I stick with that or is there a way where I can get the next line of instructions and only need to have the .exe and the .bat files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use the `^` character to escape your line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1016552/87698) and send everything to your program. However, it's not very elegant and the [length of the command line is limited](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3205027/87698).

Alternatively, if you want to stick to two files, you can create the third file on demand:

```
echo update [Server1 IP] /var/root/site > %temp%\myinstructions.txt
echo update [Server2 IP] /var/root/site >> %temp%\myinstructions.txt
echo update [Server3 IP] /var/root/site >> %temp%\myinstructions.txt
echo update [Server4 IP] /var/root/siteA >> %temp%\myinstructions.txt
echo update [Server4 IP] /var/root/siteB >> %temp%\myinstructions.txt
SSHUpdate.exe "SSHPWD" "Username" "Password" "%temp%\myinstructions.txt"
```

Comment: I love it!!, don't need to change anything in my code just my bach file