# Bat Script Mass Escape Code?

Tags: batch-file

I'm using a bat script that writes code for a bat script to a text file and was wondering if there was a way to mass escape the code and treat it as text?

At the moment I'm using the below but it's not escaping the code

```
@echo off
(
echo code
echo code
)>"text.txt"
```

Comment: Could you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015163/heredoc-for-windows-batch ? It's about the emulation of heredoc in windows batch, maybe that approach works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=[]" %%n in ('find /n "REM DATA:" "%~dpnx0"') do set /a n=%%n
more +%n%  "%~dpnx0">myNew.bat
REM rest or your batchfile
goto :eof
REM DATA:
@echo off
echo this is your new batchfile
echo on computer %computername%
REM etc.
```

the `for` just gets the line number where your new content is stored (start of DATA section), the `more` command writes that content to a new file (in fact "the currently running batchfile, skipping the first n lines").

The code after `REM DATA:` isn't processed by the parser (just copied by `more`), so no escaping needed.

Note: `more` converts TABs to (several) spaces.