# How to send command to cmd?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like to write while executing a bat file.

I have to type user and password after executing a command. When executing the command I have the following output:

```
You have been directed successfully.

Usernae =
```

After the user enters the username manually it asks for the password.

```
You have been directed successfully.

Usernae = user

password =
```

How can I create a batch script to write this user and password without being asked to type?

Comment: You can put username in a file and redirect it to standard input. [read more](http://www.ustrem.org/en/articles/redirecting-input-output-streams-en/), Heredocs are the other solution ([more details ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015163/heredoc-for-windows-batch)).

Comment: `(echo user&echo secret)|application.exe` might work (depends on how the application is programmed).

Comment: Please search the site before asking questions, I'm relatively confident that questions which involve inputting names and passwords are asked several times every week.

Comment: So, I agreed with @Stephan because I have some many software particularly developed in FORTRAN and they don’t accept arguments and others things like this in script bat.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SendKey` in VBS to send this input.

[image]

---

Just replace the placeholder values in the following code with the actual values:

```bat
set "_user_=user-x" & set "_pwd_=password-y"

set "_exec_=drive:\path\to\your\executable.exe"
```

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & cls

mode con cols=70 lines=20 & color 9F

set "_user_=user-x" & set "_pwd_=password-y" 

set "_exec_=drive:\path\to\your\executable.exe"

>"%temp%\_temp_file_4vbs_.vbs"^
    (
     echo/ Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
     echo/ Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
     echo/ StrUser  = "!_user_!"
     echo/ StrPwd  = "!_pwd_!"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 1000
     echo/     Wscript.Sleep 1000
     echo/ for h=1 To Len^(StrUser^)
     echo/     x = Mid^(StrUser,h,1^)
     echo/     WshShell.SendKeys x
     echo/     Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ Next
     echo/     Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({ENTER})"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ for j=1 To Len^(StrPwd^)
     echo/     x = Mid^(StrPwd,j,1^)
     echo/     WshShell.SendKeys x
     echo/     Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ Next 
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({ENTER})"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({ENTER})"
    ) 

set "_temp_vbs=%temp%\_temp_file_4vbs_.vbs" & cls && start "" /b "!_exec_!"

@"%Windir%\System32\cScript.exe" //nologo "!_temp_vbs!" & del /q /f "!_temp_vbs!" & goto :eof
```

Comment: The script on this **.gif** are using one FORTRAN software that don’t use or accept any code (available by google search or in **SO**) to  receive any argument.